# Single-page web application with multiple frameworks has duplicate class names

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, singlepage, html-framework-7

I'm writing a single-page web application, but I'm struggling with some frameworks.

It seems almost every modern framework, like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Framework7](http://framework7.io/)
uses *very* basic classnames like `row` or `navbar`.

Because of this I can't use both frameworks on a webpage at the same time, which is limiting my options. For some pages (like a homepage) Bootstrap is nice, but for other pages I prefer the components of Framework7.

Is there any way to solve this problem, other than using entirely different HTML-files ?

Comment: I think most people would discourage the use of multiple css frameworks on one page. They're pretty heavy and would require a substantial amount of work to get them to play nicely together. I would recommend using one framework customized to your liking to standardize the look and feel of your entire site.

Answer (score 0):

The following options can be used to namespace CSS:

- iframe per framework
- Create a SASS file which namespaces each framework using the cascade by prefixing each framework rule with a selector which maps to a parent element with the specified class name.

**References**

- [How to namespace Twitter Bootstrap so styles don't conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966259/1113772)
- [Prevent iFrame from taking parent CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296779/1113772)